# Showing svg files over each others in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Is it possible to add svg icons like files on top of another svg file, i'm using a simple object tag for my html code and i was wondering if i could add more svg files on top of the one that already shown

```
<object id="topOBJ" data="worldHigh.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="1000" height="1000">Your browser doesn't support this type of files</object>
```

Comment: You'd have to position them like any other overlay.

Comment: is it possible to position them over a certain location in the first svg file that holds a unique id of it's own ?

Comment: I doubt it...I think this is the drawback of using the `object` tag. If you use an actual SVG, with it's own viewbox you can have other SVG elements within it,

Comment: Yes there is an actual svg with it's own elements and even it's own unique id's for each element well they are in XML not html this is why i'm kinda confused and i want to position other svg elements on top of the elements that are already on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [the answer by Lau](/a/50277369/2579117), if you insist on using `<object>`-elements you can overlay them using CSS positioning,

```css
.combined {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.combined > :first-child ~ * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class=combined>
 <object data="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/svgs/fi-annotate.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
 <object data="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/svgs/fi-arrows-compress.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

The CSS in the example ensures the wrapping element (`<div class=comined>`) takes up the dimensions of the first object and overlays all other elements.

There is a nicer alternative though, using SVG to combine the other SVGs

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
 <image width="50" xlink:href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/svgs/fi-annotate.svg" />
 <image width="50" xlink:href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/svgs/fi-arrows-compress.svg" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to put one on top of each other. Extra tip! absolute items are relative to the closest parent with `position:relative` so you can use that to avoid them from flying all over the page.